# parse and sort links

Tags: php, parsing, sorting

I would like to parse and sort set of links
here is the example

Form code

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="test.php">
<textarea id="url" name="url"></textarea>
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and i will submit the following links each per line

```
http://www.google.com/moo
http://www.yahoo.com/boo
http://www.google.com/zee
http://www.bing.com/kee
http://www.yahoo.com/foo
```

this is `2 on google` and `2 on yahoo` and `1 on bing` links

the `test.php` code will be as following (where the form send the submit)

```
<?PHP
$url=$_POST['url'];
$url=nl2br($url);
$url=explode("<br />",$url);
foreach ($url as $value ){
$encrypt = md5($value);
echo $encrypt . "<br>";
}
?>
```

output will be as following

```
8ec5ec689ab94e5df9d89cea624e7e5e //google.com/moo
b165a8209254d205a2950f23214125ec //yahoo.com/boo
fc8d853005d21a7fc8abb06aba0756fb //google.com/zee
f691aab0c39f288f503ae61d3cc3b5b4 //bing.com/kee
8f55ee4d5227f87ec1316e0fa6c61e3b //yahoo.com/foo
```

**Now my question**

I would like to parse the host to know which one on `google,yahoo and bing` and sort it then showing the results exactly as following

```
google.com // parsed and sorted
fc8d853005d21a7fc8abb06aba0756fb //google.com/zee
8ec5ec689ab94e5df9d89cea624e7e5e //google.com/moo

yahoo.com // parsed and sorted
b165a8209254d205a2950f23214125ec //yahoo.com/boo
8f55ee4d5227f87ec1316e0fa6c61e3b //yahoo.com/foo

bing.com // parsed and sorted
f691aab0c39f288f503ae61d3cc3b5b4 //bing.com/kee
```

so in words i mean i would like to sort the links upon thier host then show reults sorted each group with under its parsed host.

i think i needs to make many `foreach` !!

any idea how to do it ~ thanks

Comment: Googling `php parse url` gives me [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) useful official documentation page, for a function that would probably solve your problem. Now do tell me how you spend more than 5 days searching, I dare you, I double dare you.

Comment: I fail to see any sort order here. What do you want to sort by exactly?

Comment: dears i meant to parse the host then sort the results each with its host !

Comment: All bow before @MadaraUchiha for he's got an eye that sees everything :D Had to say this :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just by extracting the domain and using it as index for an array with the encrypted values, like so:

```
$url=$_POST['url'];
$url=nl2br($url);
$url=explode("<br />",$url);
$urls = array();
foreach ($url as $value ){
   $arr = explode('www.',$value);
   $encrypt = md5($value);
   $urls[$arr[1]][]= $encrypt; //this line now fixed, had an error
}
foreach($urls as $key => &$val) {
   echo $key . "<br>";
   foreach($val as $v) {
      echo $v . "<br>";
   }
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Try again, I've updated the code in my answer, it had an error.

Answer (score 2):

### Code:

```
$urlByHost = array();
foreach (explode("\n", $_POST['url']) as $value) {
    $parse = parse_url($value);
    $urlByHost[$parse['host']][] = array(
        'url' => $value,
        'parse' => $parse,
        'md5' => md5($value),
    );
}
asort($urlByHost);

print_r($urlByHost);
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
    [www.bing.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://www.bing.com/kee
                    [parse] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http
                            [host] => www.bing.com
                            [path] => /kee_
                        )

                    [md5] => e69d3a5bb987448e30ec8559c3634caf
                )

        )

    [www.google.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://www.google.com/moo
                    [parse] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http
                            [host] => www.google.com
                            [path] => /moo_
                        )

                    [md5] => f98f559bb167acb6413b55c6c7b7255a
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://www.google.com/zee
                    [parse] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http
                            [host] => www.google.com
                            [path] => /zee_
                        )

                    [md5] => 717b78e3db16982d77dde33991c4db70
                )

        )

    [www.yahoo.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://www.yahoo.com/boo
                    [parse] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http
                            [host] => www.yahoo.com
                            [path] => /boo_
                        )

                    [md5] => b237c6cd567aaef629d55ae53f52dc49
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://www.yahoo.com/foo
                    [parse] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http
                            [host] => www.yahoo.com
                            [path] => /foo
                        )

                    [md5] => bd34d7a6adf909e4ce355b038e8d206c
                )

        )

)
```

I think that there is all the data you need.

Comment: thanks a lot works perfect, that is exactly i was talking about - this example will helps me a lot to understand further complex examples.